# PetaPcoro T4 template compilation error

Tags: asp.net, petapoco

I am running PetaPoco template T4 on my database and it generates the following error:

```
Running transformation: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one     matching element
```

Reported from the file 'database.tt

My database is modeled correctly, however most of the tables have no records, although I tihnk that it's nothing to do with it, is it?

I'm querying a MySQL local database. I've setup the connection string in the web.config and this is the only connection string in the web.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday I had same issue, I also use MySQL and last Nuget package. First of all I found that generation works on all databases, I try solution from [official page](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/):

```
DatabaseName = "name";
```

But I found that it doesn't understand variable `DatabaseName` and now it called `SchemaName`. This fix errors on unknown tables.

Second I found that it throw exception on tables with multiple PK, so open `Database.cs` after T4 template compilation and check last table. My solution was to remove generation from primary key in `PetaPoco.Generator.ttinclude` and then manual editing.

Also, you can look at: [In PetaPoco, how to decorate a table that has multi-columns primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258553/in-petapoco-how-to-decorate-a-table-that-has-multi-columns-primary-keys)

Comment: Michael Dimoudis took the time to rewrite the T4 templates to handle composite keys.  Here's the repo -> https://github.com/michaeldimoudis/PetaPoco/tree/master/PetaPoco/Models/Generated

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more info, such as a stack trace ? VS usually goes to the location of the error for me, but initial errors sometimes crop up before the actual template parsing begins.
You haven't accidentally made a second copy of the connectionstring in the config file ?