# In PetaPoco, how is it possible to define a table with 2 primary keys?

Tags: petapoco

I saw on different forums that it's possible to define 2 primary keys for 1 table like this :

```
[PetaPoco.PrimaryKey("key1,key2")]
```

But When I try to do that :

```
db.SingleOrDefault<ObjectModel>(Object);
```

I have an error message :

```
System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type AutomationTests.DataAccessLayer.Models.ObjectModel to a known managed provider native type.'
```

What's the problem ? Is it really possible to use multi-keys with Petapoco ?

Answer (score 0):

Here would be your answer : [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258553/in-petapoco-how-to-decorate-a-table-that-has-multi-columns-primary-keys)
In short, there is no official support for combined primary key columns (Yet?)